# Eclipse does not reload compiled css while running

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, less, wro4j

**TLDR;**

Eclipse does not seem to detect changes in compiled css file and does not reload them on a running server.

**Problem**

I can successfully generate css files from less files using [wro4j](https://github.com/wro4j/wro4j) everytime i update a less file.

I have followed [this](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/spring-and-angular-js-a-secure-single-page-application) tutorial from the official spring boot website itself.

Text from the tutorial

> The wro4j-maven-plugin has some Eclipse integration features and you
>   can install it from the Eclipse Marketplace (try it later if this is
>   your first time - it’s not needed to complete the application). If you
>   do that then Eclipse will watch the source files and re-generate the
>   outputs if they change. If you run in debug mode then changes are
>   immediately re-loadable in a browser.

I have used the [wro4j eclipse integration](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/m2e-wro4j) which re generates the output if the source less file changes, but these changes are not re loadable in the browser.

However, If I manually modify the compiled css after generation, the change is successfully reloaded by eclipse/spring-boot. 
So currently after i make changes to the less files, css files are generated but is not picked up by the running server. I have to open the compiled file, type a space and do a backspace and save it, only then it's reloaded.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

EDIT:
Eclipse is reloading all the changes except if the file has been auto generated.
For eg. If i modify one of my html files it reloads them right away.
But if i modify a less file, which in turn modified the css file.. this stays the same..even after restart.

I thought it could have also been because of caching now but i tried these settings and it still doesn't work

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.resources.cache-period= 5
spring.resources.chain.cache=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set *Refresh using native hooks or polling* to true.

> window-> preferences-> general -> workspace -> Check  *Refresh using
>   native hooks or polling*

Hope that helps

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. I added some more info on the problem

Comment: @user2049132 is it changing your css files when you open them within eclipse? I would check if the browser is caching those css files in the network tab in the console

Comment: I checked the network tab and it's not caching the css file besides trying the Ctrl + F5 key to refresh.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't  got more ideas. :-(