# Eclipse CSS Debug w/ Sass Not Loading Changes

Tags: css, eclipse, debugging, sass

My Eclipse project uses Sass. When running in debug mode, sass:watch (configured per [this article](http://cleancodejava.com/auto-compile-sass-stylesheets-with-maven/)) correctly polls for changes to *.scss files, compiles them into CSS and places them in the target directory. However, these changes are *not* reflected on the page, and inspecting the page using Chrome developer tools shows the new CSS is not picked up.

Using another (CSS-only) project works as expected: any change to CSS is copied to target directory, and a refresh of the page reflects the proper change.

I ran across [a similar issue someone had using LESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293373/eclipse-does-not-reload-compiled-css-while-running). Unlike that situation, though, even changing the target CSS directly, the change is not reflected in the browser.

I can't be the only person debugging Sass/CSS in Eclipse, but I can't find any info on this problem.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

EDIT: SCSS is being compiled to CSS and copied to the target build directory, but *not* into the Tomcat deployment where the code is running. As I've said, this is not an issue with CSS-based projects, only with this where it's a compiled file.

Comment: If the CSS is complied properly as you say, then the issue is checking the URL to the CSS, and ensuring it's loading and not getting cached by the browser.  I often have to clear / refresh cache when developing using SASS / CSS watchers.

Comment: I've tried clearing cache + hard refresh to no avail.

Comment: Is the CSS url correct? That's a huge component (trust me, it happens to the best of us!)

Comment: Where is Eclipse involved in this? Is it doing part of the deployment?

Comment: cale_b: I was not looking in the correct spot. The target directory is updated, but the tomcat deployment directory (from which everything runs) is not

Comment: nitind: Eclipse is running the project in Tomcat; it also does the maven builds (including on-the-fly scss compilation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem...

An entry needed to be added to Eclipse’s Web Deployment Assembly so that Eclipse would see this dynamically-generated folder and associate it with the project.

The files were being generated to the *local_repo/target/branch_name* directory, where *branch_name* was dynamic, and dependent upon what branch you were working on; this made it impossible to create a static entry in Eclipse WDA for us.

Our solution was to have Maven (1) create a *sass-generated/css* directory under *local_repo/target*, and (2) copy the css over into the *branch_name/static* directory where it belongs.

Now, when debugging locally and running Sass Watch, changes to *.scss files are detected, compiled to css, and deployed to the *sass-generated/css* directory. Since this dir is associated with the project in Eclipse WDA, Eclipse sees the change and deploys it to Tomcat as expected!